# How to use webjars with Maven without any framework

Tags: java, jquery, maven

I did not find an answer for the specific scenario I am working on. I have a Maven Web Project, which I want to run on a Tomcat Server (which is working fine so far). My problem is, that I need to use jQuery and Bootstrap, but it does not work and the official resources do not provide a way to use it without any additional framework.

That is what I have done so far:

- My pom.xml looks like this and has all the necessary dependencies:

  ```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

         <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
         <groupId>de.ls5.wt2</groupId>
         <artifactId>micro</artifactId>
         <packaging>war</packaging>
         <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
         <name>micro Maven Webapp</name>
         <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
         <dependencies>
           <dependency>
             <groupId>junit</groupId>
             <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
             <version>3.8.1</version>
             <scope>test</scope>
           </dependency>
            <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                   <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
                   <version>0.1</version>
               </dependency>
               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                   <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
                   <version>0.32-1</version>
               </dependency>
               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                   <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
                   <version>3.2.0</version>
               </dependency>
               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                   <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
                   <version>3.3.7</version>
               </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
               <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
               <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
           </dependency>
         </dependencies>
         <build>
           <finalName>micro</finalName>
         </build>
       </project>
  ```
- The target/appName/WEB-INF/lib folder contains the jar files for jQuery, Bootstrap and all of the other dependent libs
- When I want to use it now in an index.html or index.jsp, it is not working and the console says that the resources can not be found. The index.html looks like this (an example from a tutorial):

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/webjars/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <title>WebJars Demo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container"><br/>
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"
                  aria-label="close">×</a>
                <strong>Success!</strong> It is working as we expected.
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

- The `index.html` is inside my `target/appName/` folder and I know the referenced file under`"target/appName/webjars/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"`which is referenced from the `index.html` does not exist, but what do I need to do know? I thought maven would do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have duplicated **webjars-locator** dependency - fix that.

---

Now, on your question:
Fix your js and css imports by removing preceding "/":
 Change `<script src="/webjars/.../>` to `<script src="webjars/.../>`

Check [full example](https://github.com/webjars/sample-jetty_war), if you want

Hope this will work.